# I have 3. What am I?

Tags: riddle

I have 3 but I give millions.
People value me higher when I give more.
People don't see my size until a couple are dead?
If I die people throw me away.
If I break you will be annoyed.
When I die I give one

Comment: Did you make this riddle yourself?

Comment: Yes and I know the answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are a

> Pixel

---

I have 3 but I give millions.

> Each pixel has [three sub-pixels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel#Subpixels), which when combined can produce millions of colors.

People value me higher when I give more.

> Greater color depth, or more colors, is considered desirable for video displays

People don't see my size until a couple are dead?

> You don't realize how small a pixel is until you have a dead pixel on your display

If I die people throw me away.

> People throw away TVs or monitors that die

If I break you will be annoyed.

> But a broken/cracked screen on its own is an annoyance, and people will still use them

When I die I give one

> A dead pixel always shows one color

Comment: Good job it that is the right answer

Comment: @VarunW.: I feel like "if I die" and "if I break" aren't referring to the actual answer. Rot13(N oebxra cvkry glcvpnyyl *vf* n qrnq cvkry, juvpu vf naablvat ohg glcvpnyyl qbrfa'g vaibyir guebjvat njnl gur cvkry. V guvax gur oebxra/qrnq yvarf gnyx nobhg gur GI/zbavgbe, abg gur cvkry vgfrys.)